# iphone 4s can connect two bluetooth 4.0 device?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

i would like to know iphone 4s can connect two bluetooth 4.0 device?

i use Corebluetooth.framework to connect my bluetooth4.0 device, now i have question if we have two device can i connect both?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

For an example, take a look at Apple's heart rate monitor sample at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011322. In HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate.m you will find the following method collecting multiple devices:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI 
{    
    NSMutableArray *peripherals = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"heartRateMonitors"];
    if( ![self.heartRateMonitors containsObject:aPeripheral] )
        [peripherals addObject:aPeripheral];

    /* Retreive already known devices */
    if(autoConnect)
    {
        [manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)aPeripheral.UUID]];
    }
}
```

In this particular sample, the app only connects with one of the heart rate monitors, but you can look at the code and easily see how it could connect to two, assuming you are willing to update the UI to show both heart rates.

Comment: but how to know the aPeripheral.UUID if more then one device.

thank you vary much~

Comment: sorry.. i test some time. but i cant connect two heart rate usb device can u help me?

Comment: There are two UUIDs involved, and that can get confusing. The service has a UUID, and that's what you use to scan. The device itself also has a UUID, and that should be unique to each device. So, when you scan for the service UUID, look at each device that is returned and check the device UUID. If that differs from one you've already seen, you have found a second device that provides the same service.

Comment: i have new question, how to control two device NotifyValue, i connected two heart rate device, but only get one device value, how to  control get two device value? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can connect if iPhone device is playing the master role. One slave device can only get connected with one master device. A BLE device including iPhone device can play both master and slave role at a time. For more information about the connection of BLE devices, you can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852662/what-exactly-is-a-ble-connected-device-on-ios/11858550#11858550).

Comment: I believe devices running iOS 5.1 can only be a master device.